# JavaFX runlater specification and performance

Tags: performance, javafx-2

I am writing a simple platformer game with JavaFX. Since I have to use `Platform.runLater()` (for adding/removing nodes), I am aware of possible performance problems in case of big stages with lots of objects -> more `runLater()` calls per second.
What is the best for perfomance: to group actions to be done in the JavaFX thread in one `Platform.runLater()` call or call it several times in one iteration? How huge impact can it make on performance and UI responsiveness?
For example, if I have, say, 20 characters on the screen that shoots bullets with 2 bullets/sec speed. This will yield 40 calls for adding node, 40 calls for removing nodes (bullets that hit surface will disappear) and several calls for other effects. How can I define which solution is better:
1. Call `runLater()` 100 times a second.
2. Group actions each frame (say 30 fps) and call `runLater()` 30 times a second.
3. Choose other solution. I am thinking about *"node pool"* that will hold some amount of nodes that are on the stage, but invisible. This will minimize the amount of `runLater()` calls to minimum.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Why do you use runLater? How many often do you use it? What is your definition of iteration? How many iterations are there and how often do they occur?  How many times is several times in this context of runlater calls?  What would constitute an impact on performance or UI responsiveness for you?

Comment: I use runlater to add or remove child nodes. On this early stage it is almost never used, but I am aware that later I would create and remove a lot of projectiles and reamins and want to know if this can slow down my engine.

Comment: You don't need to reply in a comment, you can edit your question to add specific info (and you'll need to if you want a good answer).  runLater is only required if you are running tasks off of the JavaFX application thread and then want to modify stuff on the application thread.  Are your projectiles created and removed off of the JavaFX thread?  If not, you don't need runLater at all and this is a non-issue for you.

Comment: I thought about moving my code into JavaFX thread, but isn't JavaFX thread responsible for user input, listeners and gui redraw?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but everyone says "JavaFx 2 can handle it's threads independently"...
I never made a big enough program to test that, but i am pretty sure JavaFx 2 can create and remove(application) threads if it needs more/less.